# Should I pointer-cast from a private derived class to its base class?

Tags: c++

I found this from C++FAQ

> Generally, No.
>
> From a member function or friend of a
>   privately derived class, the
>   relationship to the base class is
>   known, and the upward conversion from
>   PrivatelyDer* to Base* (or
>   PrivatelyDer& to Base&) is safe; no
>   cast is needed or recommended.
>
> However users of PrivatelyDer should
>   avoid this unsafe conversion, since it
>   is based on a private decision of
>   PrivatelyDer, and is subject to change
>   without notice.

How to understand the above words? I don't think the explanation is correct or accurate.

I have a code like this

```
class A{
};

class B: private A{
};

int main(){

    B *b = new B();
    A *a = new A();

    a = b;                    //wrong
    a = (A*)b;            //right

}
```

Comment: The implicit cast doesn't compile (A is inaccessible base), and the second one uses a C-style cast, that is the equivalent of `reinterpret_cast` here?

Comment: yes you're right, reinterpret cast is evil as we all know. what he did in last line isn't a good practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a purely mechanical viewpoint, you're right: a cast to a private base class will work and produce working results.

The point of the FAQ is that from a design viewpoint it's generally wrong. Private inheritance is really supposed to mean private -- in other words, even though it may work, you're not supposed to know it'll work, and at some point it may quit working -- since it's officially an implementation detail, not part of the public interface, they could re-implement the class without using inheritance. At that point, the cast wouldn't work any more (but because you've used a cast, the compiler probably won't warn you about it having gone from something you probably shouldn't do to something that can't possibly work at all).

Edit: Yes, the cast *does* necessarily work. According to §5.4/7 of the standard:

> ... the following static_cast and
>   reinterpret_cast operations
>   (optionally followed by a const_cast
>   operation) may be performed using the
>   cast notation of explicit type
>   conversion, **even if the base class
>   type is not accessible**:
>
> — a pointer to an object of derived
>   class type or an lvalue of derived
>   class type may be explicitly converted
>   to a pointer or reference to an
>   unambiguous base class type,
>   respectively;

[emphasis added]

Comment: @Konrad:one of those rare times that I'm not sure learning something new was such a great thing! I almost wish I didn't know, because then there would be no temptation to use it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the explanation is correct. It says that even though a cast is possible from `B` to  `A` it should not be done. The reasone is that the inheritance is *private* and should be considered an implementation detail of `B` that the users of the class should never care of. It is just the same rules as anything marked `private` - it should be considered internal to the class. Outside clients should only rely on the `public` functions and attributes - including `public`inheritance.

Personally I have never found any use for private inheritance - I think that it is often better to use composition.

Comment: @Anders: private inheritance makes sense when coupled with policy classes (such as `std::allocator`): such classes are often empty. Having them as private members would still consume memory because every member of a class must have a distinct address, even if the member doesn’t need the memory. Inheriting from them, however, will *not* consume needless memory.